# Resizing Wrapper

Tags: html, css

Having an issue resizing the #main_wrap on:

http://www.coffeeproteindrink.com/method-athlete/

```
#main_wrap {
min-height: 100%;
background: url(images/content_back.png) repeat-y top left; 
margin: 0 0 0 240px;
opacity: .8;
}

#content
{float: left;
margin: -28px 0 30px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 20;
top: 325px; 
height: 262px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

I am trying to get it to look like:

http://www.bio-genix.com/

I am sure I am just having a brain fart, but I just can't seem to get this to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Ken

Comment: Welcome! Please reduce your source markup and CSS to that which you think is causing/underlying your problem and include in the question body. Use the **`{}`** button after highlighting code to format it in your text. `:)` And/or make a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: If you don't even allow us to right-click your page (what a barbaric thing to do! absolutely awful. you have crushed me), there's little we could do to help you :)

Comment: That 'no right click' is built into this theme, I disabled it, sorry about that.

Comment: You need to better describe the problem itself. Do you not want the scrollbars to appear? Also, `float`ing your `#content` container...

Comment: Also, just some advice, look and see if [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/) has a font you can use. Cufon is bleh.

Comment: The problem is, I can't figure out how to resize the wrapper down to look like that of bio-genix. Yes, I want the scroll bars there. :)

Comment: So you don't want `Method Athlete` white text up at the top?

Comment: I'd rather it not be, but it isn't really my main concern. The whole open black area above the #content container is what I'd like to size down.

Comment: I think you want this: `position: absolute; top: 325px;` on `#main_wrap`, not on `#content`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You've got the `top: 325px` on the wrong element. If you don't have it, get Firebug for Firefox or use Chrome Console and inspect your elements above `#content`.

Comment: I have firebug, will try that now

Comment: Something like this? http://jfcoder.com/test/methodsite.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Jared. Looks almost perfect now, I appreciate it!

Comment: If that's the answer, I'd like to post it. At that point you could upvote and/or mark it as the answer. That's how the site works. `:)`

Comment: Am I allowed to upvote yet? I don't think i have enough rep do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `top: 325px` value is on `#content`, which is further down than where you want to be in element list. Hence, you want to push down `#main_wrap` with `top`, and remove the `top` from `#content`.

```
#main_wrap {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 325px;
} 
#content {
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/methodsite.html

Comment: Thanks Again Jared, As soon as I have enough rep I will be sure to mark this up.

Comment: Yeah, I forget all the arcane vote and comment and whatnot rules SO has. You're welcome, glad I could help. And thank you for marking returning to mark the answer; that's appreciated, believe me. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing to do is (if having access to CSS) go down to your #Content tag

```
#content {
float: left;
margin: -28px 0 30px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 20;
top: 325px;
height: 262px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

And remove overflow:scroll, as your content divider is large enough to handle the content without having to overflow. So it should look like this

```
#content {
float: left;
margin: -28px 0 30px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 20;
top: 325px;
height: 262px;
}
```

Comment: I want the scroll bars there, as I want to keep the wrapper to about 40% of the page height. Like it is on http://www.bio-genix.com/ Some pages will have more content than others and the scroll bars will be needed.

Comment: So do you mean, you want it to scroll, but not have them be there? I see they dynamically placed their wrappers. EDIT: Try overflow:hidden;

Comment: The problem was the black transparent background going up to the top of the viewport, not the scrollbars.