# Issue with removing padding or margin

Tags: css

http://www.coffeeproteindrink.com/method-athlete/

I am trying to remove the open space below the main wrapper, in Firefox it shows about a 20px open area, with a verticalscroll bar on the main page in order to see it.

In IE there is a visible 115px area, with no scroll bar.

My goal is to have the main_wrap + footer sit flush to the bottom of the page, but nothing I am trying is seeming to help.

```
#main_wrap {height: 390px;
background: url(images/content_back.png) repeat-y top left; 
margin: 0 0 0 240px;
opacity: .8;
position:absolute;
top:325px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#main
{position: relative;
width: 680px;
padding: 0 40px 5px 40px;
font: normal 12px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 2;
}

#footer
{ 
width: 680px;
padding: 25px 40px 0 0px;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
height: auto;
clear: both;
bottom:50px;}
```

Example of what I am trying to accomplish: http://www.bio-genix.com/

Thanks for any help,
Ken

Comment: If you want `#main_wrap` to sit at the bottom of the page, how come you're anchoring it from the top with the `top` property?

Comment: You're looking for a Sticky Footer technique. I like [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/), which is CSS only. There are others.

Comment: @Utkanos - See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277452/resizing-wrapper). The OP doesn't yet know how to push content to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I've tried bottom 0 and top 325, it does the same thing Utkanos, I'll check that out Jared and report back. Thanks

Comment: Use absolute positioning doesn't necessarily work. Getting things to "stick" to the bottom of the viewport is trickier than you probably think.

Comment: That post you linked me too is a bit too complex for me, The css is easy enough. But it needs you to add html into the site. And tracking down the correct areas in php files (wordpress) gives me headaches..lol I changed the top:325px back to bottom:0 and it did remove quite a bit of the open space in IE, but also added a scroll bar now like in FF. Any other noob friendly suggestions? lol Thanks

Comment: This is working in Firefox: http://jfcoder.com/test/methodsite.html

Comment: It's also working in IE9, Opera 12 and Chrome. IE7 is the only one that shows a problem, and a conditional could be devised to fix that. for IE7 only. All the others look great (I can't get Safari to run on my computer).

Comment: What is working Jared? Also, i just found this: http://www.wordimpressed.com/wordpress/put-a-css-sticky-footer-in-your-wordpress-theme/

Comment: I notice that if i set the height of #main_wrap to 450px, it removes the scroll bar, but the transparent black bg is just too big on the bottom.

Comment: The link to the page on my site, http://jfcoder.com/test/methodsite.html It's sitting right at the bottom like you want it, I thought.

Comment: Almost at the bottom Jared, there is still a couple px there though, hence the scrollbar..but the height showing on the main_wrap is bigger than the actual one on the live site. And it shows underneath the footer.

Comment: I know what happened; you're editing the CSS and it was working until you modified something. I literally, *literally*, had it working perfectly a few minutes ago.

Comment: I haven't edited anything, other than in firebug...other than changing that top:325px to bottom:0

Comment: It looks like the it's padding on `#main h2.section_title`. Go to my page and zero out the margins on that and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Yea, I see what you're saying. But it still leaves about 75px of black transparent space under the footer after those are zeroed out.

Comment: just edited my css to reflect that change

Comment: I literally had it: http://imgur.com/nR9BM

Comment: Me changing the h2 padding screw it up? I can change it back.

Comment: No, it's the positioning and what not on the element in `main_wrap`. Also, you are seriously abusing header tags. That paragraph text should be in... Paragraph tags. Won't solve the problem per se, but just saying.

Comment: HOLD ON. Don't touch anything.

Comment: Ok, put the `margin: 20px 0 40px` back on the headers and add `overflow: hidden` to `#main_wrap`. That hides the extra space that the margins/paddings of the internal elements create when they push stuff down.

Comment: There you go. Now check http://jfcoder.com/test/methodsite.html

Comment: Has anyone ever told you 'You're the Man!'?

Comment: Nice. Allow me to make the pitch again for forgoing Cufon and going with web fonts (Google Web Fonts catalog is pretty nice). I've seen so many problems with Cufon, I just don't trust it.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for all the help you gave me today Jared. If I could email you a beer or 12, I would instantly :)

Comment: No problem. I'll write it up in answer here in a minute.

Comment: Yea, I'll check out webfonts tomorrow..It's past my bedtime..work at 5:30am..ugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you don't need a sticky-footer technique because your background image is stretching to the screen, meaning you can use `height: 100%` and it's reliably set to the full height.

So, seeing that, `bottom: 0` will work on `#main_wrap`. The next puzzle was where the phantom `60px` or so of bottom margin was coming from; finally, after tweaking, it was determined that `overflow: hidden` would hide the additional height that was developed by the margins and paddings within the `#main_wrap` element.

This is what ended up working (the `h2` part a fix for a fix):

```
#main_wrap {
    position: absolute;
    height: 390px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
#main_wrap #main h2.section_title {
    margin: 20px 0 40px
}
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/methodsite.html

Comment: The Man, The Myth, The Legend! :)  Thanks So Much Again Jared, VERY Much Appreciated!